# Using silhouette clustering criterion on TDAmapper output Ask

Tags: r, clustering, high-dimensional

I have performed several kind of cluster analysis: hierarchical cluster analysis, mclust analysis for high dimensional dataset and TDA mapper which uses cluster analysis also.

Now, I would like to understand which of these analysis could cluster better my data, so analysis using silhouette index may be a good solution.

Of course, for hierarchical and mclust analysis I have no problem using silohuette analysis but for TDAmapper there is the problem of overlapping.

How can I evaluate the output of TDAmapper and compare to the other analysis? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For TDA, you have a free parameter of persistence, which will unambiguously fix your clusters when you set it to a given value. However, TDA does *not* return centroids. Much in the same way that tSNE returns an embedding, it's up to you to specify centroids. You could run k-means on your TDA result, using graph distance as your metric, to then fix clusters. Then silhouette analysis should be applicable.

Comment: The silhouette index doesn't require centroids.